# why Python string changes to italic looking in the Canopy editor when moved to new line?

Tags: python, canopy

This is probably an editor snag. But thought to check in case, as I do not know Python and just started to learn it.

Comparing the following

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And I simply move the second field one line below by hitting return

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code in the second line became italic. I thought at first I have some syntax error or the editor is warning me about something, but there is no problem and the code run just as before. This only happens when the `"""` use. With a single `"` then the code does not become italic.

Do you think this is just an editor issue, or is the editor trying to tell something I should not be doing?

Specs:
Windows 7, [Enthought Canopy 1.5.4](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html) (64 bit)

code in plain text:

```
   data = [r"""123""",r"""456"""]
```

Comment: """ is used for docstrings, not for normal strings. you should use single or double quotes. and it is most definitely an editor thing

Comment: @LawrenceBenson  I use `r"""` all the time. It is for multi line raw strings and use it to generate Latex code from Python all the time with no problem. It is like HERE-DOCUMENT.  It is just a string and can use all string operations on it.

Comment: Triple quotes can also be used to more easily enter a large string, or to avoid needing to use lots of escapes for a string that contains both kinds of quotes.

Comment: nonetheless, it is some kind of highlighting in you editor

Comment: Looks like a buglet to me. Thanks for the report.
-- Enthought Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see the documentation for your editor, I would guess that the italics is there to signify that the line is wrapped and is not trying to warn you of anything. 
As stated in [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), "Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and braces, or using a hanging indent". wrapping lines like you're doing is completely ok and the editor shouldn't be warning you of anything.